# I want to generate the pdf and save it in library?

Tags: plugins, php, plugin-development

i am using this code to generate pdf

```
$base64_pdf = "data:application/pdf;base64,base64encodedpdf".base64_encode($result);
            //$base64_pdf = $result;

            $pdf_base64_handler = fopen($base64_pdf,'r');
$pdf_content = fread ($pdf_base64_handler,filesize($base64_pdf));
fclose ($pdf_base64_handler);
//Decode pdf content
$pdf_decoded = base64_decode ($pdf_content);
//Write data back to pdf file
$pdf = fopen ('test.pdf','w');
fwrite ($pdf,$pdf_decoded);
//close output file
fclose ($pdf);
echo $pdf;
var_dump($pdf);
echo 'Done';
```

**the output now is**
Resource id #617resource(617) of type (Unknown) Done

how i can generate the pdf and it save in library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Saving in Wordpress library can be done by using this function [media_handle_upload](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/media_handle_upload/).

PDF can be created in many ways. The best method depends on your runtime enviroment and the functionality you are looking for. There are several PDF generating libs for PHP out there, for example [PDFlib](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdf.php). But again your question is far broad.